# Question regarding faithfully flat module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $\phi: R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. Prove that $S$ is faithfully flat $R$-module  iff $\phi$ is injective and $S/\phi(R)$ is flat R-module

Although I am able to prove faithfully flat implies the injectivity, I am unable to prove $S/\phi(R)$ is flat $R$-module. So, any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: if $\phi$ is injective, isn't $Ker \ \phi=0$ ?

Comment: Sorry i gave wrong information it has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the short exact sequence of $R$-modules 
$$0\rightarrow R\xrightarrow{\phi}S\rightarrow \frac{S}{\phi(R)}\rightarrow 0$$ Fix any $R$-module $M$. Then we get a long exact sequence in homology $$...\rightarrow Tor_2^R\left (\frac{S}{\phi(R)},M\right )\rightarrow Tor_1^R(R,M)\rightarrow Tor_1^R(S,M)\rightarrow Tor_1^R\left( \frac{S}{\phi(R)},M\right)\rightarrow M \rightarrow M\otimes S\rightarrow M\otimes \frac{S}{\phi(R)}\rightarrow 0 $$ We know $Tor_1^R(S,M)=Tor_1^R(R,M)=0$ .

Since $S$ is faithfully flat we also know $M \xrightarrow{m\mapsto m\otimes 1} M\otimes S$ is an injective map. Thus the long exact sequence gives us $$Tor_1^R\left( \frac{S}{\phi(R)},M\right)=0$$ for any $R$-module $M \implies \frac{S}{\phi(R)} $ is a flat $R$-module.

Edit:

Since $S$ is faithfully flat we know $N\otimes S=0\implies N=0$

Suppose $m\otimes 1=0$ in $M\otimes S\implies m\otimes s=0$ in $M\otimes S$ by considering the map $id\otimes \lambda_s :M\otimes S\rightarrow M\otimes S$ where $\lambda_s$ is the map multiplication by $s$.

Thus we can conclude $Rm\otimes S=0\implies Rm=0\implies m=0$

Comment: Ohhh makes sense. But is it possible to do it without tor man. This answer is right so far I think

Comment: Btw this line S is faithfully flat, then $M \rightarrow M\otimes S$ is injective map. What's the proof of this one.

Comment: I can't immediately think of a solution without using $Tor$. If I can, I will post it. Also I would be interested in seeing a solution without using $Tor$.